# Please explain, how this style works?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, styles

```
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="30" />
                <Setter Property="Image.Width" Value="24" />
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
```

The first 2 setters work as expected. The last setter applies width to all elements, images and text blocks too. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `Image.Width` refers to the [`FrameworkElement.Width`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width.aspx) property via the `Image` class. In other words, you're resolving the `FrameworkElement.WidthProperty` field by by way of the `Image` class, which inherits it from `FrameworkElement`.

If you want the width only to apply to images, use a separate style that with a `TargetType` of `Image`.

Comment: @user626528 - WPF Styles are no like CSS. This means you can't set properties on child elements using a Style. I suspect in your Style above, you expect all the Images in a DataGridCell to have their Width set to 24. That's not what is going to happen. You can only set properties on the DataGridCell using the Style above. The fact that the Image.Width and DataGridCell.Width property are effectively the same property, means the above will set the Width of the DataGridCell.

Comment: @CodeNaked, thanks, clear. But, is there any other way to set properties for the specified child elements type inside the style target element?